# Unit testing with Jest, expect problem receiving empty/undefined object

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, sinon

i am new to unit testing and i am trying to test the length of a navigation bar, below you can see the nav bar component which is within a class

```
<AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static">
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
            {authenticated && this.state.layoutMode ==='desktop' ? (
                <Grid container
                    direction ="row"
                    justify="flex-end"
                    alignItems="center">
                    <div className={classes.root}>
                        <Tabs id="Tab" className = {classes.tabBar} value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                            <Tab label="example" alt="example" onClick={() => Router.push('/example')}/>
                        </Tabs>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            ) : (
                authenticated && <BurgerMenu/>
            )}
```

Below is the test i have written so far

```
describe('NavBar', () => {
const intialState = {
    ui: { width: 1361 },
    auth: { authenticated: true }
}

let container;
beforeEach(() => {
    container = shallow(<Nav />);
});

it('should render self and subcomponents', () => {
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('should contain an AppBar', () => {
    console.log(container.find(AppBar));
    expect(container.find(AppBar)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

})

however my problem is that the .find(AppBar) doesnt seem to be found, when using a console log(container.find(AppBar)) it shows the following "ShallowWrapper {}" this would mean that the object is empty and therefore not equal to 1, however i do not know where to point the find to correctly find the tabs to test

Comment: Try `console.log(container.debug());` within one of your tests. This will show the `DOM` structure as `enzyme` sees it. Then you should be able to determine whether or not you'll need to `dive()` into a component to find `AppBar` (if you're diving too much, just use `mount` instead of `shallow`).

Comment: Thanks so much this debugging process helped allot, after changing container - mount(<Nav/>) my test passed!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
let container;
beforeEach(() => {
    container = mount(<Nav />);
});
```

diving to deep within the DOM with shallow.